# Odd JavaScript Behavior When Comparing Numbers Larger than 1000

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

I wrote a javascript function that is supposed to check if an amount is greater than 0 and less than a certain amount. For example, if the total amount due is $800.00, and the user tries to pay $1100, I want the function to first check that the amount being paid ($1100) is greater than 0 (true) and that the amount being paid is also less than the total amount due (false). I was pretty sure my logic was fine, but this function hasn't been working correctly:

```
function validate_payment_amount() {
    var payment_amt = get_amount_paying(); // 1100.00
    var amt_due = get_amount_due(); // 800.00

    console.log('Is ' + payment_amt + ' greater than 0?: ' + (payment_amt > 0));
    console.log('&&');
    console.log('Is ' + payment_amt + ' less than or equal to ' + amt_due + '?: ' + (payment_amt <= amt_due));

    return payment_amt > 0 && payment_amt <= amt_due;
}
```

The function evaluates correctly if `payment_amount` is **less than 1000**, here is the console output:

```
Is 999.00 greater than 0?: true
&&   
Is 999.00 less than or equal to 892.50?: false
```

So the above works fine. However, when I give it a number **greater than 1000**, this is what the console displays:

```
Is 1001.00 greater than 0?: true
&&
Is 1001.00 less than or equal to 892.50?: true
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

**EDIT:**
`get_amount_paying()` and `get_amount_due()`:

```
function get_amount_due() {
    return parseFloat($("#still_due").data('amount')).toFixed(2);
}

function get_amount_paying() {
    return parseFloat($("#make_payment").val()).toFixed(2);
}
```

Comment: Are `payment_amt` and `amt_due` being evaluated as strings or floats?

Comment: It is highly suspicious. May be your data type is not exactly a `number`, may be it is coming as a `string`?

Comment: Are you sure sure the vars are numbers and not strings?

Comment: Yup, please see the edit

Comment: @AndrewDeForest see my answer about toFixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output gives away the fact that they are strings - printing actual number type would never have extraneous 0s. Seeing `892.50` when printing a number is impossible.

`.toFixed()` returns a string, not a number btw.

It works for `> 0`, because when comparing `string > number`, the string is automatically parsed into a number before comparison.

It doesn't work for `payment_amt <= amt_due` because they are both strings, thus a string comparison is done and nothing is parsed for their numeric value.

Try

```
function get_amount_due() {
    return parseFloat($("#still_due").data('amount'))
}

function get_amount_paying() {
    return parseFloat($("#make_payment").val())
}
```

The difference is removal of `toFixed`, which is useless here.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification about toFixed()! Would have never even thought that would be the source of the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Are you perhaps comparing strings rather than numbers?  That would explain your results.

Try this instead:

```
var payment_amt = parseFloat(get_amount_paying());
var amt_due = parseFloat(get_amount_due());
```

(See the [parseFloat docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).)

**Edit:** `toFixed()` returns a string - see the [toFixed docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Comment: I added the functions (which both return floats) for clarification.

Comment: @AndrewDeForest: No, `toFixed()` returns a string.